# Flutter: The argument type 'MultiProvider Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This flutter code throws **The argument type 'MultiProvider Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)'**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(460,790),
      builder: () => MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => api()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => PageControllerProvider()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => RequestProvider()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => HistoryProvider()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeProvider()),
        ],
        child: App()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone has an suggestion to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71698583/11675817

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

wrap you `ScreenUtilInit` with a `Builder` widget as shown in the code bellow .

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(
       builder : () => ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(460,790),
      builder: () => MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => api()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => PageControllerProvider()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => RequestProvider()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => HistoryProvider()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeProvider()),
        ],
        child: App()
      ),
     )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It trows an error too like I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the ScreenUtilInit package to the latest version. In the latest version (^5.5.3+2 at the time of writing), the signature of the builder parameter is changed to `Function(BuildContext context, Widget? child)`